# Multiformat text parser in Python

Tags: python, beginner, parsing

I am working on a small [textract](https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)-based Python CLI tool that aims to extract text from either a single or multiple files, writing the output in corresponding text files. The input files can be of any of the formats that textract supports.

The full repository is [here](https://github.com/rdimaio/parsa). (Forgive me for the lack of a README file for now, I am planning to expand the project)

My main concerns:

- Does the structure of the project make sense?
- Are small functions (like `_process_text` in `utils/text.py`) worth being defined on their own, or should they be integrated into bigger functions? (like `get_text` in the previous example)
- Have the modules and functions been documented correctly?
- Are there any obvious mistakes I'm making in the way I'm handling exceptions?

Apart from these main points, I am open to all kinds of feedback!

## **parsa.py** (main file)

```
import os
import utils.cli as cli
import utils.filesystem as fs
import utils.text as txt

# Get CLI arguments
args = cli.parse_arguments()

# If input is a file
if os.path.isfile(args.input):

    # Set IO variables
    infile = args.input
    indir = os.path.dirname(infile)
    outdir = fs.set_outdir(args.output, indir)

    # Extract text
    text = txt.get_text(infile)

    # If text has been extracted successfully (and infile was not empty)
    if text:
        outfile = fs.compose_unique_filepath(infile, outdir)
        try:
            fs.write_str_to_file(text, outfile) 
        except OSError as e:
            print(e)

# If input is a folder            
elif os.path.isdir(args.input):

    # Set IO variables
    indir = args.input
    outdir = os.path.join(fs.set_outdir(args.output, indir), 'parsaoutput')

    # Create output folder
    os.makedirs(outdir, exist_ok=True)

    filelist = fs.get_filelist(indir)

    for infile in filelist:
        text = txt.get_text(infile)
        if text:
            outfile = fs.compose_unique_filepath(infile, outdir)
            try:
                fs.write_str_to_file(text, outfile) 
            except OSError as e:
                print(e)


else:
    exit("Error: input must be an existing file or directory")
```

## **utils/cli.py**

```
"""utils/cli.py - Command-line utilities for parsa

Classes:
    _SmartFormatter - allows formatting in the CLI help menu

Functions:
    parse_arguments - parse CLI arguments
    _set_arguments - set CLI description and arguments
"""

import argparse

class _SmartFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):
    """Allows formatting in the CLI help menu.
    Called by beginning a string with R| in _set_arguments().
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/22157136
    """
    def _split_lines(self, text, width):
        if text.startswith('R|'):
            return text[2:].splitlines()  
        # this is the RawTextHelpFormatter._split_lines
        return argparse.HelpFormatter._split_lines(self, text, width)

def parse_arguments():
    """Parse command-line arguments, and return a Namespace object containing them."""
    argparser = _set_arguments()
    # Parse arguments into Namespace
    args = argparser.parse_args()
    return args

def _set_arguments():
    """Set CLI description and arguments."""
    argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=('Textract-based text parser that supports most text file extensions. '
    'Parsa can parse multiple formats at once, ' 
    'writing them to .txt files in the directory of choice.'), formatter_class=_SmartFormatter)

    argparser.add_argument('input', help=('input file or folder; if a folder is passed as input, '
    'parsa will scan every file inside it recursively (scanning subfolders as well)'))

    # TODO - describe what the stats file will include
    argparser.add_argument('--stats', '-s', nargs='?', help='output stats file')

    argparser.add_argument('--output', '-o', nargs='?', default=None, help=('R|folder where the output files '
    'will be stored. The default folder is: \n'
    '(a) the input file\'s parent folder, if the input is a file, or \n'
    '(b) a folder named \'parsaoutput\' located in the input folder, if the input is a folder.'))
    return argparser
```

## **utils/filesystem.py**

```
"""utils/filesystem.py - OS/filesystem utilities for parsa

Functions:
    compose_unique_filepath - compose a filepath to avoid overwriting existing files
    get_filelist - return list of files of a directory and all subdirectories
    set_outdir - set output directory based on the user's choice
    write_str_to_file - write string to file
"""

import os

def compose_unique_filepath(infile, outdir):
    """Compose output filepath to avoid overwriting existing files.

    If a file with the same name as the output file already exists in the output directory, 
    the input file's extension will be included in the output file's name before the .txt extension.
    (e.g. if foo.txt already exists, foo.pdf will be extracted to foo.pdf.txt)

    An incrementing counter will be included before .txt to identify subsequent extractions with the same name.
    (if foo.pdf.txt exists as well, foo.pdf will be extracted to foo.pdf2.txt, with 2 being the incrementing counter)
    """

    # Get input's filename with neither its path nor extension
    # e.g. /home/testdocs/test.pdf -> test
    filename_noextension = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(os.path.splitext(infile)[0]))
    # Create path for output file
    # os.path.join intelligently creates filepaths that work cross-platform
    # e.g. /home/testdocs/ + test.pdf -> /home/testdocs/test
    outfilepath_noextension = os.path.join(outdir, filename_noextension)
    outfile = outfilepath_noextension + '.txt'

    file_exists_counter = 1

    # This loop is only entered if the outfile already exists
    while os.path.exists(outfile):
        input_extension = os.path.splitext(infile)[1]
        # If it's the first iteration, just add the input extension to the filename
        if file_exists_counter == 1:
            outfile = outfilepath_noextension + input_extension + '.txt'
        # Otherwise, add a counter too
        else:
            outfile = outfilepath_noextension + input_extension + str(file_exists_counter) + '.txt'
        file_exists_counter += 1
    return outfile

def get_filelist(indir):
    # TODO - check this with a lot of files, because theoretically you're going through 2 for loops for each file and that might be inefficient (O(n) still)
    """Return list of files in the input directory, including the files in all subdirectories.""" 
    filelist = []
    # Cycle through all files in the directory recursively
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/36898903
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(indir, topdown=True):
        # Remove the parsaoutput folder from the list of directories to scan
        # (allowed by topdown=True in os.walk's parameters)
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/19859907
        dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d != 'parsaoutput']
        for filename in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            filelist.append(filepath)
    return filelist

def set_outdir(args_outdir, indir):
    """Set output directory based on whether a custom outside directory was provided or not, and return it."""
    # If output directory wasn't provided, set it to the input directory
    if args_outdir == None:
        outdir = indir
    else:
        outdir = args_outdir
    return outdir

def write_str_to_file(text, outfile):
    """Write input text string to a file."""
    with open(outfile, "x") as fout:
        fout.write(text)
```

## **utils/text.py**

```
"""utils/text.py - Text utilities for parsa

Functions:
    get_text - extract text from the input file
    _process_text - process extracted text and return it as a simple string
"""

import os
import textract

def get_text(infile, _infile_extension=None):
    """Extract text from the input file using textract, returning an empty string if failing to do so.
    If the infile does not explicitly have an extension (UnicodeDecodeError), 
    the user will be prompted to input the correct extension (either with or without a dot). 
    get_text is then recursively called with _infile_extension set to the input extension.

    The caller should never set _infile_extension to anything in most cases, 
    unless they want to skip the prompt for input extension and the entirety of the input is of the same format.
    """
    # If text is not extracted or the infile is empty, the function will just return an empty string
    text = ''   

    try:
        text = textract.process(infile, extension=_infile_extension)
    # File existence gets checked in parsa.py
    except textract.exceptions.ExtensionNotSupported:
        print("Error while parsing file: " + infile)
        print("Extension not supported\n")
    # Skip file if parsing has failed
    except textract.exceptions.ShellError as e:
        print("Error while parsing file: " + infile)
        print(e)
    # If the file has no explicit extension, prompt the user for it
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        print("Error while parsing file: " + infile)
        print("File has no extension\n")

        # Prompt the user for the input file's extension
        # textract.process adds a dot before the input extension if it's not already present (e.g. txt -> .txt)
        _infile_extension = input("Please input the file's extension (e.g. .pdf or pdf):")

        # Call the function again; an exception will be raised on failure
        text = get_text(infile, _infile_extension)
    # If no exceptions happened, format text adeguately
    else:
        # Extract input file's extension unless it has already been specified
        if not _infile_extension:
            _infile_extension = os.path.splitext(infile)[1]

        text = _process_text(text, _infile_extension)
    return text

def _process_text(text, _infile_extension):
    """Process extracted text and return it as a simple string."""
    # utf-8 is used here to handle different languages efficiently (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2438901)
    text = text.decode('utf-8')
    # Remove unnecessary trailing space caused by the form feed (\x0c, \f) character at the end of .pdf files
    if _infile_extension == '.pdf' or _infile_extension == 'pdf':
        text = text.strip()
    return text
```